# Python List of nparray to list

Tags: python, list

I've searched for hours now a way to convert a list of nparray to a list.
The output of the function I use is :

```
[array([[[ 65, 172]], [[ 64, 173]], ... , [[ 65, 173]]]),
array([[[ 70, 144]], [[ 70, 145]], ... , [[ 71, 144]]]), 
array([[[ 71, 132]] ,[[2, 1]]])]
```

When I select the first item with list[0], I get :

```
[[[ 65 172]] [[64 173]] ... [[65 173]]]
```

So what I want now is to get something like that, where all the elements are in one list, but not seperated with comas or semicolon :

```
[[[ 65 172]] [[64 173]] ... [[ 71 132]] [[2 1]]]
```

Is there anything in python that can convert my list of nparray to the output list I want to get, or to concatenate/join each item of the list into one ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you print the shapes of all your arrays? `print [x.shape for x in data]`. And can you elaborate what you want your output shape to be?

Comment: @NilsWerner I'm new to python I don't know how to differentiate data types. 
I get [(19, 1, 2), (9, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2), (14, 1, 2), (12, 1, 2), (760, 1, 2), (632, 1, 2)] when I use shape on the output I get.
I can add lists together but I get a coma between each item : [[[65, 172]], [[64, 173]], ... ,[[65, 174]], [[65, 173]]]. What I want is the same output without comas.
Also, if I use data[0] in the function I want to use it works, but with the one I just show you it says "not a numpy array neither a scalar".

Comment: @NilsWerner Here you have the shape of the output I want (I took it from the item data[0]) : [(1, 2), (1, 2), ... , (1, 2)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should disregard the commas in the output. They are just text output but not part of the data. Instead, start thinking about your array shapes. As per your answer earlier you have a list of arrays, each with shapes

```
[(19, 1, 2), (9, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2), (14, 1, 2), (12, 1, 2), (760, 1, 2), (632, 1, 2)]
```

To create one big array where you keep dimensions `1` and `2` and simply attach your arrays along their axis `0` you can simply use `numpy.concatenate`. The expected output shape should be

```
(x, 1, 2)
```

where `x` is the sum of all first dimension shapes:

```
import numpy

# Random data, shapes taken from your answer earlier
data = [numpy.random.rand(19, 1, 2), numpy.random.rand(9, 1, 2), numpy.random.rand(1, 1, 2), numpy.random.rand(14, 1, 2), numpy.random.rand(12, 1, 2), numpy.random.rand(760, 1, 2), numpy.random.rand(632, 1, 2)]

# Concatenate along axis 0. All other dimension must be equal in shape!
out = numpy.concatenate(data, axis=0)

print out.shape  # (1447, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it works well ! I wasn't doing the first instruction so the concatenate was not working.